# Search and Replace comment out entire line Java/Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

Say I have a line

```
blah.field
```

that needs to be commented out

```
//blah.field
```

which is referenced in a project in multiple files

Is there a way to comment this line in all places using a simple eclipse search and replace?

Comment: If you have this need in a programming language editor, you are doing something wrong. Commenting out code is a bad practice. Delete it instead (as it can always be restored from the version control system, if necessary). And if you have to remove a field declaration in many files, you might also want to look at encapsulation and abstraction again, as that field should probably declared only by one super class that all your other classes derive from.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should show a minimal understanding of the problem, show attempts and explain what when wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Replace regular expression:

```
^blah\.field$
```

with

```
//$0
```

- ^ = begin of line (here)
- $ = end of line
- $0 = the entire found match

Comment: +1 but what has he tried? ;)

Comment: Must be beginner, but I like it, that he thinks of using smart replaces.